# Changing Nav Font-colour using Bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I tried several different approaches to change the colour of my nav bar buttons but none of them worked. It's my first time using bootstrap so it comes down to not understanding how to customise my website using CSS on top of BS.

The code below was what I used in my last attempt, using an answer found here: [changing font color in bootstrap nav bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739315/changing-font-color-in-bootstrap-nav-bar)

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent mynav" style= "color:red !important;">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

What's the best approach? Inline, in the head of the html file, using a custom CSS (I don't use sass)

Comment: I'm glad that helped you! Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue completely. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read about **[CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)**.

There are many ways to accomplish what you want. I'll show you a way:

- Add an unique **`id="<idName>"`** to the **`<ul>`** tag like so:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="navbar_links" class="navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Features</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**[ID Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors)** have more weight on **[CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)**.

- Now you can use the `id` to access the `<li>` tags like so:

**CSS:**

```
#navbar_links li a {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add some css in your code

```css
.navbar-nav li a {
    color: black !important;
}

.navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: red !important;
}
```